# Replacing columns of a CSV with a string using awk and gsub

Tags: awk

I have an input csv file that looks something like:

```
Name,Index,Location,ID,Message
Alexis,10,Punggol,4090b43,Production 4090b43
Scott,20,Bedok,bfb34d3,Prevent
Ronald,30,one-north,86defac,Difference 86defac
Cindy,40,Punggol,40d0ced,Central
Eric,50,one-north,aeff08d,Military aeff08d
David,60,Bedok,5d1152d,Study
```

And I want to write a bash shell script using `awk` and `gsub` to replace 6-7 alpha numeric character long strings under the ID column with "xxxxx", with the output in a separate .csv file.

Right now I've got:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '{gsub(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){6,7}/g, "xxxxx", $4);}1' input.csv > output.csv
```

But the output from I'm getting from running `bash myscript.sh input.csv` doesn't make any sense. The output.csv file looks like:

```
Name,Index,Location,ID,Message
Alexis,10,Punggol,4xxxxx9xxxxxb43,Production 4090b43
Scott,20,Bedok,bfb34d3,Prevent
Ronald,30,one-north,86defac,Difference 86defac
Cindy,40,Punggol,4xxxxxdxxxxxced,Central
Eric,50,one-north,aeffxxxxx8d,Military aeff08d
David,60,Bedok,5d1152d,Study
```

but the expected output csv should look like:

```
Name,Index,Location,ID,Message
Alexis,10,Punggol,xxxxx,Production 4090b43
Scott,20,Bedok,xxxxx,Prevent
Ronald,30,one-north,xxxxx,Difference 86defac
Cindy,40,Punggol,xxxxx,Central
Eric,50,one-north,xxxxx,Military aeff08d
David,60,Bedok,xxxxx,Study
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown sample, please try the following code:

```
awk -F ',[[:space:]]+'  -v OFS=',\t' '
{
  sub(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){6,7}$/, "xxxxx", $4)
  $1=$1
}
1
' Input_file | column -t -s $'\t'
```

***Explanation:*** Setting field separator as comma, space(s), then setting output field separator as comma tab here. Then substituting from starting to till end of value(6 to 7 occurrences) of alphanumeric(s) with `xxxxx` in 4th field. Finally printing current line. Then sending output of `awk` program to `column` command to make it as per shown sample of OP.

***EDIT:*** In case your Input_file is separated by only `,` as per edited samples now, then try following.

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '
{
  sub(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){6,7}$/, "xxxxx", $4)
}
1
' Input_file
```

Note: OP has installed latest version of awk from older version and these codes helped.

Comment: Is the reason for setting the field separator as comma, space and comma tab in this case due to the sample I showed, as in my actual csv file there are no commas or tabs between the entries. I just formatted it this way for the post to make it more readable

Comment: @bakedgoods, if you have a file called csv format that it should be comma separated. As per your shown samples you needed nice alignment in output, so keeping output separator as `,\t` will make separator as comma tab. Then passing it to column command will make it look like how you want in final output IMHO.

Comment: Unfortunately the code didn't work. The output I got looks like
```Name,Index,Location,ID,Message
Alexis,10,Punggol,4090b43,Production 4090b43
Scott,20,Bedok,bfb34d3,Prevent
Ronald,30,one-north,86defac,Difference 86defac
Cindy,40,Punggol,40d0ced,Central
Eric,50,one-north,aeff08d,Military aeff08d
David,60,Bedok,5d1152d,Study
```

Comment: @bakedgoods, this is a tested code with your shown samples, is your actual file is same as shown samples?

Comment: I tried with a test file which follows my samples, but I still get the original csv back with the fields under ID unchanged

Comment: @bakedgoods, this code will print data on terminal. Do you want to save output into file itself? Please confirm once.

Comment: I want to save the output into a new csv file. (in my script I had `input.csv > output.csv`) at the end. I've edited the question to avoid any confusion with regards to the csv files

Comment: @bakedgoods, ok, please try my EDIT code then in that case, let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233834/discussion-between-baked-goods-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: NOTE: Updating to newest version of gawk has also helped OP with these answers.

Answer (score 3):

The short version to your answer would be the following:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}(FNR>1){$4="xxxxxx"}1' file
```

This will replace all entries in column 4 by "xxxxxx".

If you only want to change the first 6 to 7 characters of column 4 (and not if there are only 5 of them, there are a couple of ways:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}(FNR>1)&&(length($4)>5){$4="xxxxxx" substr($4,8)}1' file
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}(FNR>1)&&{sub(/.......?/,"xxxxxx",$4)}1' file
```

Here, we will replace 123456abcde into xxxxxxabcde

**Why is your script failing:**

Besides the fact that the approach is wrong, I'll try to explain what the following command does: `gsub(/([a-zA-Z0-9]){6,7}/g,"xxxxx",$4)`

The notation `/abc/g` is valid awk syntax, but it does not do what you expect it to do. The notation `/abc/` is an ERE-token (an extended regular expression). The notation `g` is, at this point, nothing more than an undefined variable which defaults to an empty string or zero, depending on its usage. awk will now try to execute the operation `/abc/g` by first executing `/abc/` which means: *if my current record (`$0`) matches the regular expression "abc", return `1` otherwise return `0`*. So it converts `/abc/g` into `0g` which means to concatenate the content of `g` to the number `0`. For this, it will convert the number `0` to a string `"0"` and concatenate it with the empty string g. In the end, your `gsub` command is equivalent to `gsub("0","xxxxx",$4)` and means to replace all the ZERO's by "xxxxx".

Why are you getting always `gsub("0","xxxxx",$4)` and never `gsub("1","xxxxx",$4)`. The reason is that your initial regular expression never matches anything in the full record/line (`$0`). Your reguar expression reads `/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){6,7}/`, and while there are lines that start with 6 or 7 characters, it is likely that your awk does not recognize the extended regular expression notation '{m,n}' which makes it fail. If you use gnu awk, the output would be different when using `-re-interval` which in old versions of GNU awk is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find why your code behave like that, for simplicty sake I made example concering only `gsub` you have used:

```
awk 'BEGIN{id="4090b43"}END{gsub(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){6,7}/g, "xxxxx", id);print id}' emptyfile.txt
```

output is

```
4xxxxx9xxxxxb43
```

after removing `g` in first argument

```
awk 'BEGIN{id="4090b43"}END{gsub(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){6,7}/, "xxxxx", id);print id}' emptyfile.txt
```

output is

```
xxxxx
```

So regular expression followed by `g` caused malfunction. I was unable to find relevant passage in GNU `AWK` manual what `g` after `/` is supposed to do.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*